# Mean of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I see that the definition of a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) uses the mean of another matrix in its definition. However, I cannot find a definition of a mean of a matrix. So how is the mean defined?

Comment: It's the mean of a vector, which is an entrywise mean.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the wiki page that you linked, we have
$$
\mu_{\mathbf X} = (E(X_1),E(X_2),\dots,E(X_N))^T.
$$

---

Taking "the mean of a matrix" is not something that makes sense unless we have further information.  In a typical application, we would have column-vectors $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \Bbb R^m$ that correspond to distinct measurements.  The data matrix corresponding to these measurements would be 
$$
X = \pmatrix{x_1 & \cdots & x_n} \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}
$$
and the mean of the data matrix (which is real the mean of our data set) would be 
$$
\mu = \frac 1n \left( x_1 + \cdots + x_n\right).
$$

Comment: What is $E(\mathbf{X}_i)$)?

Comment: The expectation (AKA the mean) of the random variable $X_i$.

Comment: But why is $\mathbf{X}_i$ a random variable when my matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is not random? It does not make sense to me. It would make more sense if we were talking about rows/columns. I am talking in the context of covariance of a matrix btw

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context to your question; the "covariance of a matrix" only makes sense if the matrix is related to random variables somehow.  In your matrix, is every measurement a row, or is every measurement a column?

Comment: See my latest edit.